# how to fix this validation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

in My controller update method is like this,

```
 public function updateOneProjectTask(Request $request, $projectId, $taskId)
        {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'task_name'  => 'required|min:3',
            ]);
                DB::table('tasks')
                ->where('project_id', $projectId)
                ->where('id', $taskId)
                ->update(['task_name' => $request->input('name'),'body' => $request->input('body')]);

            return redirect()->back()->with('info','Your Task has been updated successfully');
        }
```

but when I am going to update My task table input it is always generating **The task name field is required** error massage. how can fix this problem?

**Updated edit blade file**
this is My blade file regarding to the task input

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('task_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" value="{!! $task->task_name ?: '' !!}">
                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>
```

Comment: what about removing the required? `'task_name'  => 'min:3'`

Comment: Post your form/blade code.

Comment: you dont have name of task_name when doing post, check it or change 'task_name' => 'min:3' to 'name' => 'min:3'

Comment: Putra your comment is working but still have some problem that is if I put task name with 2 letters it is not print error massage but it is automatically fill with deleted letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your field name is just "name" (because you used $request->input('name') in your update method), so your validation should be the following:

```
$this->validate($request, [
   'name'  => 'required|min:3',
]);
```

**Update**

You can trim request using following line before validation:

```
$request->merge(array_map('trim', $request->all()));
```

Furthermore you need to update your blade error checking and replace **task_name** with **name**:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
...
```

Comment: this is working but still have some problem. that means if I put task name with two letters it is not print validation error massage. instead it is refresh to 3 characters.

Comment: @John may be you have extra space in your input. it should work. If you update your question with the related part of your blade template, then we can help more

Comment: looks like you forgot to rename "task_name" in blade template. see updated answer.